# Still not display expandable content

Tags: android, notifications

My code:

```
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "channel_name";
        String description = "channel_description";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(default_notification_channel_id, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, default_notification_channel_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_mobile_main_btn)
            .setContentTitle("textTitle")
            .setContentText("textContent")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line.Much longer text that cannot fit one line.Much longer text that cannot fit one line."))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(( int ) System. currentTimeMillis () , builder.build());
```

Problem: display only "textTitle" and "textContent"
I Expected: display bigText

Do I wrong something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problems about version change and now I fixed!.